# Progression bar sync javascript to server time?

Tags: javascript

I have an object which contains some data about progression of a bar but it keeps stopping at 99% and won't continue, i believe its because client time is not going to be the same as server time accurately enough to do it. So i don't know how to solve it.

These 2 timers are created server side and sent to the client.

```
myOjb[i].end: 1374805587 //seconds since epoch for when 100% is made
myObj[i].strt: 1374805527 //seconds since epoch when it started
```

The function that is calculating the percentage :

```
function clocker() {
    var now = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    for (var i in myObj) {
        if (myObj[i].end > now) {
            var remain = myObj[i].end - now;
            var per = (now - myObj[i].strt) / (myObj[i].end - myBuildings[i].strt) * 100;
            var per = fix_percentage(per); // stops > 100 and < 0 returns int if true

            myObj[i].percentage = Math.ceil(per);

            console.log(myObj[i].percentage); //reaches 99 max

            if (myObj[i].percentage > 99) {
                console.log('test'); //never occurs
                return false;
            }
            break;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    setTimeout(clocker, 1000);
}

function fix_percentage(per){
    if(per>100)per=100;
    if(per<0)per = 0;

    return Math.round(per);
}
```

How could i sync the two together so the timing is more accurate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Original answer was based on a bad assumption. I think what is happening is that essentially your block setting the percent to 100 might be getting skipped. This would happen if on one iteration, the value of `per` was < 99.5 but > 88.5. In this case, the rounded `per` would have a value of 99. Then, one second later when the function gets called again, the outer if block would not be entered due to `myObj[i].end > now` being `false`. The following code will make sure that if time expires and the `myObj[i].percentage` is < 100 because of the above scenario, it will be set to 100 and return like the other if block does.

```
if (myObj[i].end > now) {
        var remain = myObj[i].end - now;
        var per = (now - myObj[i].strt) / (myObj[i].end - myBuildings[i].strt) * 100;
        var per = fix_percentage(per); // stops > 100 and < 0 returns int if true

        myObj[i].percentage = Math.ceil(per);

        console.log(myObj[i].percentage); //reaches 99 max

        if (myObj[i].percentage > 99) {
            console.log('test'); //never occurs
            return false;
        }
        break;
    } else if ( (now >= myObj[i].end) && (myObj[i].percentage < 100) ) {
        console.log('Time expired, but percentage not set to 100')
        myObj[i].percentage = 100;
        return false;
    } else {
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: Of course, this whole answer is based on an assumption on the behavior of fix_percentage.

Comment: i have added the function my Q so you can check ?

Comment: Yes, the error is based on `if (myObj[i].end > now) {` causing **completion** (the 100% status) of the block/unit of work to mostly be skipped.

Comment: Check out the updated answer for something that should work for you. The explanation is just a theory about why you are not getting to 100. It's not necessarily what's happening in your scenario, but it shouldn't matter what my theory is. The above code WILL set the percentage to 100 if the timer has expired and the percent was not otherwise set to 100 elsewhere.